# Do I use <b> or <mark> to highlight key marketing words in paragraph?

Tags: html

I have a paragraph of text in which I need to highlight some key words. I'm struggling to understand the difference between the `<b>` and `<mark>` tags. The text is highlighted because they are key marketing words, so the copywriter wants to draw attention to them.

For the `<b>` tag, the [W3C documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-b-element) says:

> The b element should be used as a last resort when no other element is more appropriate [...] text marked or highlighted should use the mark element.

But for the `<mark>` tag it says:

> When used in the main prose of a document, it indicates a part of the document that has been highlighted due to its likely relevance to the user's current activity

So, in a body of marketing copy, are there any advantages (SEO, accessibility, or otherwise) to using the `<mark>` tag over the `<b>` tag?

---

**Extra clarification:**

The kind of copy that I'm marking up looks like

> We are great at *this* and *that*, and we are the *best in the world*.

It's those bits that are in italics there that I need to markup.

Also, I'm using HTML5, so the `<b>` tag is not deprecated.

Comment: you can also use `<strong>` tag to highlight your text

Comment: Apparently `<strong>` is for verbal emphasis - if I read it back to myself, I don't think there would be any verbal emphasis. The text is along the lines of 'we specialise in *this* and *that*'.

Comment: What or who are you trying to attract to the marketing keywords?  Is it a human or a search engine spider?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips Both. I'm wondering what the pros and cons are for humans and search engines.

Comment: If it were me I'd probably wrap the areas of text with span tags and apply CSS styles to it to achieve whatever visual effects I wanted.  Then I'd look towards providing more information in meta keywords and description tags/attributes in the page header.  A lot of people choose to put a block of text in the footer of each page to add company information for search engines, although many search engines are clever enough to detect if text is little contrasting colour to the background or too small to read and mark you down for it.  Sorry to not be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tags have significantly different uses.

`<b>` is for applying a bold font weight to a sections of text, whereas `<mark>` is for highlighting/marking text.

If you want to wrap a portion of text for an unspecific reason you should be able to use `<span>` tags and anything SEO should ignore them.

Comment: In HTML5, the `<b>` tag is not presentational. The full quote from the W3C documentation "The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key words in a document abstract." I'm drawing attention to these words, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing it for utilitarian purposes. (It is advertising.)

Answer (score -1):

I would place the key marketing words between "span" tags and define a new class.
In the CSS-file, you can then define this new class as being bold.

Comment: I would suggest the mark, since the bold tag will be deprecated.

Comment: No, the `<b>` tag is back in HTML5, though with a technically different meaning. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-b-element

Comment: I found this on the W3C website:"According to the HTML 5 specification, the b tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML 5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the h1 to h6 tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the em tag, important text should be denoted with the strong tag, and marked/highlighted text should use the mark tag." Hopes this answers your question.

Comment: Yep, already read (and quoted) that bit - I'm not sure if drawing attention to marketing keywords is a 'last resort'.